# String to text field in android app

Tags: android

I have the following data scanned from a pdf417 and need to extract certain text to certain text fields (already created), not sure how to go about this... Data scanned with manatee works plugin and android app using android studio.

All help will be appreciated.

Data that was returned from scan -
%MVL1CC18%0154%4025M003%4025012RP01C%DC62XBGP%NISSAN%SILVER/SILWER%

Each part between the %'s need to go to a text field. I know that I need to make use of `String substr=mysourcestring.substring(startIndex,endIndex);` but this will work up to the first 2 % signs. How do I continue to the next few?

Thanks.

Comment: show your relevant code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use [String.split()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String))?

In your case it would look something like this:

```
String[] extractedStrings = mysourcestring.split("%");
```

Comment: Maybe use `mysourcestring.substring(1).split("%")` to get rid of the first empty string in the array.

Comment: Thank you all, all answered around the same. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

If you want to split string based on a delimiter, use the following

```
String delimitter="%";
String[] parts = inputString.split(delimitter);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can work on your string by using `split` method:

```
String yourString = "%MVL1CC18%0154%4025M003%4025012RP01C%DC62XBGP%NISSAN%SILVER/SILWER%";
String[] split = yourString.split("%");
```

In this way you will get an array where each item is a substring between two `%` chars.